# Rules for upconverting/downconverting types

Tags: c

Are there any rules at a function-level for what numeric types are allowed to be passed to it without a warning? For example, if we take the following two functions:

```
void take_int(int n){};
void take_double(double n){};
```

And calling it as:

```
take_int(4);      # as intended
take_double(4.0); # as intended
take_double(4);   # have to up-convert int to double
take_int(4.0);    # have to down-convert double to int
```

When would this raise a warning or not be acceptable (ignoring what the actual function does with the values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is valid C, so it should be accepted by any compiler.

I tried your code in some recent versions of clang and GCC using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), with the `-Wall -Wextra --pedantic` warning options, and none of them gave warnings.

However, the C standard does not specify what warnings a compiler should give, so the warnings you get will depend on what specific compiler you are using, and what version.

Comment: I see, so when it puts `4.0` into `%rdi` to pass to `take_int`, it first converts that to a four-byte int before putting it in the register, or how does that work when it has to implicitly cast the number?

Comment: The compiler knows that `take_int` takes an `int` argument so it will definitely convert `4.0` into the equivalent integer value and pass that to the function, using whatever the calling convention is on your platform.  It won't do anything crazy.